# Unfindable unsatisfiable constraints

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I am getting this astonishing amount of broken constraints when executing my project in the main view with no reference to actually present objects - all my objects in the view are named, while here the error refer to generic objects - and with none of the breaking values to be found in any file of the project. The visualization of the view is not affected, but I would prefer to submit the app without any broken constraint.

```
2016-04-17 20:31:24.431 iPuja[2460:1299842] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x154653250 H:[UILabel:0x154656480'0'(26)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465f6e0 H:[UILabel:0x154656480'0']-(22)-[UIImageView:0x15465bf90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465f730 UIImageView:0x15465bf90.centerX == UIView:0x15465cef0.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465fc80 UILabel:0x154656480'0'.leading == UIView:0x15465cef0.leadingMargin + 2>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465feb0 H:[UIImageView:0x15465bf90(240)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1545b11f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x15465cef0(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465feb0 H:[UIImageView:0x15465bf90(240)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-04-17 20:31:24.433 iPuja[2460:1299842] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x154653250 H:[UILabel:0x154656480'0'(26)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465f6e0 H:[UILabel:0x154656480'0']-(22)-[UIImageView:0x15465bf90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465f730 UIImageView:0x15465bf90.centerX == UIView:0x15465cef0.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465fc80 UILabel:0x154656480'0'.leading == UIView:0x15465cef0.leadingMargin + 2>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465fe60 H:[UIImageView:0x15465bf90(360)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1545b11f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x15465cef0(375)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465fe60 H:[UIImageView:0x15465bf90(360)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-04-17 20:31:24.434 iPuja[2460:1299842] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465ff00 V:[UIImageView:0x15465bf90(70)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465ff50 V:[UIImageView:0x15465bf90(73)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465ff50 V:[UIImageView:0x15465bf90(73)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-04-17 20:31:24.434 iPuja[2460:1299842] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465f690 UIView:0x15465cef0.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x15465bf90.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465f780 UIView:0x15465cef0.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x15465bf90.bottom + 2>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15465f780 UIView:0x15465cef0.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x15465bf90.bottom + 2>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Of course no error is reported in the storyboard.

Comment: From this message it is obvious, you are setting some constraints twice, for example UILabel:0x154656480. You should check your labels constraints in interface builder.

Comment: based on the error you should check for the UILabel and UIImageview constraints and try to remove the unnecessary constraints

Comment: Would help if you can add a screenshot of how you set up the constraints.

Comment: The point is that those failing constraints are not even present in my storyboard. I already wrote I use names for objects, and those are not reported in the error message to allow me to check what are the affected objects; but most importantly I checked all my project for the numbers reported along the objects (like 70, 73, 360), and I do not find even them.
What sort of screenshot could I submit?